How to get idToken ( Auth key) for firebase with ESP8266 using AT commands
I was trying to connect to firebase using AT commands on ESP8266 (ESP01).
Without authenticated rules I'm able to write to a node.
But with authenticated rules, I'm having a trouble getting Auth Key.
With curl it is working fine but AT commands returns error.
These are the curl commands which works to get Auth key using web API key.
curl -X POST -d "Content-length:63" "https://identitytoolkit.googleapis.com/v1/accounts:signInWithPassword?key=<API_KEY>&email=<email>&password=<password>&returnSecureToken=true"

which works fine and returns idToken that can be used as <Auth_key> for posting to firebase node like below.
curl -X PUT https://myproject-default-rtdb.asia-southeast1.firebasedatabase.app/UsersData/mynode.json?auth=<idToken>  -d "{\"Test\":\"data\"}"

But when I try using the same using AT commands with ESP8266 (ESP01) it does not works.
To get token key I tried to connect to server using below command,
AT+CIPSTART="SSL","https://identitytoolkit.googleapis.com/v1/accounts:signInWithPassword?key=<API_KEY>",443

but it return error.
I tried also
1) AT+CIPSTART="SSL","https://identitytoolkit.googleapis.com/v1/accounts:signInWithPassword",443

2) AT+CIPSTART="SSL","https://identitytoolkit.googleapis.com/v1/accounts:signInWithPassword?key=<API_KEY>&email=<email>&password=<password>&returnSecureToken=true",443

All returns error.
How do I get token id from google API using AT command?
Below connection is successful, but I need to authenticate using token key.
AT+CIPSTART="SSL","myproject-default-rtdb.asia-southeast1.firebasedatabase.app",443


esp8266 AT firmware doesn't support TLS 1.2 and higher

Thanks for the hint. I was unaware of this. I will try update the ESP8266 AT firmware with https://github.com/JiriBilek/ESP_ATMod which claims support for TLS 1.2.

I tried  AT+CIPSTART="SSL","https://identitytoolkit.googleapis.com",443 this command succeeded connecting to server. But consequent transfer returned error. Tried with original AT firmware and modified "github.com/JiriBilek/ESP_ATMod" firmware.

how are you invoking the AT commands? from a terminal? it is not possible to do a HTTP request that way

I use Arduino Serial Monitor. It is little difficult to use as we need to quickly send the data in seconds but it works with simple web links. Any how I can try by code, but what is the correct sequence of data to send for getting the Auth code? The below code succeeds presently AT+CIPSTART="SSL","https://identitytoolkit.googleapis.com",443

do you have an Arduino which will use the esp-01 as a WiFi adapter? then you can use my WiFiEspAT library
